# LibUsbDotNet -unable to find the usb device error

Tags: c#, .net, libusb, libusbdotnet

Using the below
 [link](http://libusbdotnet.sourceforge.net/V2/Index.html) as reference, I try to communicate with USB from my PC.

The below code

```
 public static UsbDeviceFinder MyUsbFinder = new UsbDeviceFinder(1234, 1);
 if (MyUsbDevice == null) throw new Exception("Device Not Found.");
```

returns Exception- Device not found.

Do libusbnet expects any driver to be installed. My default my usb device is listed in the drives but unable to detect from program. what should be the value to be given in the pid & vid? How to find it out from device manager?

Also I tried to fetch the list of usb ports and find the pid and vid from that but it not listing any relevant data in that.
[Show info](http://libusbdotnet.sourceforge.net/V2/Index.html)

Comment: please post more code. this code won't compile as is.

Comment: I added the link which i used for reference.

Answer (score 0):

First of: Yes you have to use a backend driver on Windows for libusb to work. But there is a InfWizard provided with LibUsbDotNet which you can use.

PID and VID can be found via Device Manager -> Device Right-click Properties -> Details -> Hardware IDs afaik.